# how to set the offset in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can set the offset using JavaScript ?

Comment: var offset = 24;

Answer (score 24):

You set the `left` and `top` CSS values.

#### With jQuery

```
$("#myEl").css({"position":"absolute","left":"100px","top":"100px"});
```

#### Vanilla JavaScript

```
var myEl = document.getElementById("myEl);
myEl.style.position = "absolute";
myEl.style.left = "100px";
myEl.style.top = "100px";
```

Answer (score 2):

If the container is scrollable, the scroll method may be more in line with the specification. If not, it has to be solved by setting the absolute positioning

[Element.scroll() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll)

```js
// Put the 1000th vertical pixel at the top of the element
element.scroll(0, 1000);

// use optionas
element.scroll({
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a class, e.g.

Jquery:
$("p:last").addClass("selected");

Javascript:
Someone has posted a JS function here - http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/542128-can-javascript-add-new-style-class

You would then need to make sure that 'selected' was defined in your style sheet. The relevant CSS properties are:

top
left
margin
padding

You probably want a combination of margin (offset outside element) and padding (offset inside element).